# How to add custom text after price in list page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, product-list

I need price like **$20.23/each**. But I tried in  $html in `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php` but its not working. Can you please anyone help me.

```
protected function wrapResult($html)
{
    $html=str_replace("</span></span>", "/each</span>", $html);
    return '<div class="price-box ' . $this->getData('css_classes') . '" ' .
        'data-role="priceBox" ' .
        'data-product-id="' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId() . '"' .
        '>' . $html . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know how you would add a text attribute instead of just /each. So for every product you could assign a different attribute /each
/phone
/charger

Answer (score 4):

The contents of the price box defined in the template are rewritten by `Magento_Catalog/js/price-box.js` after page load. That bit of javascript contains the template used for the price box. You can use a mixin to adjust the template format.

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
  config: {
    mixins: {
      'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box': {
        'Vendor_Module/js/price-box-mixin': true
      }
    }
  }
};
```

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/price-box-mixin.js`

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

  return function (widget) {
    var globalOptions = {
      productId: null,
      priceConfig: null,
      prices: {},
      priceTemplate: '<span class="price"><%- data.formatted %>/each</span>'
    };

    $.widget('mage.priceBox', widget, {
      options: globalOptions
    });
    return $.mage.priceBox;
  }
});
```

The result after page load is:

[image: Result after page load]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in v2.2.3. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

You can find file at `Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml`
you can adjust your text at above html.

Don't forget to override this core file to your module/theme.

Answer (score 0):

magento\vendor\magento\module\catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml

```
<?php $taxDisplay = $this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->getPriceDisplayType();?>
<?php if (Magento\Tax\Model\Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_INCLUDING_TAX == $taxDisplay): ?>
     <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Inc. VAT') ?>
<?php elseif (Magento\Tax\Model\Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_EXCLUDING_TAX == $taxDisplay): ?>
     <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Excl. VAT') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```